# How to force reboot ubuntu system when it hangs?

Tags: freeze

What is the command that is used to reboot the system in case of ubuntu Freezing and unable to do any operation ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/36717/158442

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you are looking for is known as `Reboot Even If System Utterly Bad` - REISUB.

So what you need to do is:

Press **ALT**+**Print Screen** and then enter the following key combination. **REISUB**

More details of the command are:

> R: Switch the keyboard from raw mode to XLATE mode
>
> E: Send the SIGTERM signal to all processes except init
>
> I: Send the SIGKILL signal to all processes except init
>
> S: Sync all mounted filesystems
>
> U: Remount all mounted filesystems in read-only mode
>
> B: Immediately reboot the system, without unmounting partitions or
>   syncing

Source https://fosswire.com/post/2008/04/ubuntu-cheat-sheet/

Comment: It is not `Alt` + the `PrintScreen` but `Alt` + the `SysRq` key you need to hold down. They just happen to be the same physical key on many keyboard layouts.

Comment: Also note that you should give the system several seconds of time between each letter, as these commands do not necessarily finish immediately. Watching the HDD activity LED of your computer can be a good indicator, you should wait for it to stay off for a few seconds before you proceed with the next letter, especially between `S`, `U` and `B`.

Comment: ^Seconded. If you're not going to wait, then you might as well press B directly.